# Accessing 2 layers password protected url by using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python, I want to send a request to a url which will return some information to me. If I try to access the url from the browser, a popup box appears and asks for a username and password. But after that I need to login again with another username and password. I have a username and password for these url and I don't know how to make python automatically complete these fields to access the URL. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: There are two ways for automating it: at the browser level by automating (browser plugins, macros, keyboard event generation) the  dialog, or at the network level by identifying what is exchanged between the browser and the server and *simulating* it from Python. Currently, it is unclear what you need.

Comment: You can use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) , it's uses for automatic browsing, it can help you.

Comment: Thank all of you for your suggestion.